# How much of the manga did the anime Akatsuki no Yona (Yona of the Dawn) cover?

Tags: yona-of-the-dawn

So I watched the anime *Akatsuki no Yona* not long ago and now I want to buy the manga. I want to buy it, however, from the point the anime left off.

Which volume of the manga it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anime series adapts the first 8 volumes (47 chapters).

The first OVA, *On That Back*, is an adaptation of volume 12's Extra chapters.

The other two OVAs, *The Yellow Dragon Zeno's Past, Part 1: The Starting Dragon* and *The Yellow Dragon Zeno's Past, Part 2: The Red Star Rises*, showing Zeno's past, cover chapters 101-105 from volume 18.